# Read column index and column value from an excel in c#

Tags: c#, .net, excel

I have a c# application which reads data from an excel file.

i used

`Range xlRng = (Range)workSheet.get_Range("A1:B6", Missing.Value);`

this to read  value from A1 to B6 cells

if i gave a range i  need to read value to a dictionary and the key name must be cell index and the value must be corresponding cell value

**Key   Value**

A1      Value1

B1      Value2

A2      Value3

B2      Value4

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could also try this

```
Excel.Range xlRng = (Excel.Range)workSheet.get_Range("A1:B6", Type.Missing);
Dictionary<string, string> dic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
foreach (Excel.Range cell in xlRng)
{

    string cellIndex = cell.get_AddressLocal(false, false, Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    string cellValue = Convert.ToString(cell.Value2);
    dic.Add(cellIndex, cellValue);
 }
```

If you would use Excel namespace as same as me, so don't forget to import namespace

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
```

I hope this will be helpfull

Comment: thank u.. string cellValue = cell.Value; modified this as        string cellValue = cell.Value2; so please edit your answer,thank u

Comment: please modify your answer

Comment: Oh, I'm so sorry for late, cell.Value works for me.
Anyway, I've changed my answer as your suggestion.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried [EPPlus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)?

Here is sample code that would do what you want:

```
void Main()
{
    var existingFile = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\book1.xlsx");
    // Open and read the XlSX file.
    using (var package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        // Get the work book in the file
        ExcelWorkbook workBook = package.Workbook;
        if (workBook != null)
        {
            if (workBook.Worksheets.Count > 0)
            {
                // Get the first worksheet
                ExcelWorksheet sheet = workBook.Worksheets.First();

                // read some data
                Dictionary<string,double> cells = (from cell in sheet.Cells["A1:B6"] 
                            where cell.Start.Column == 1
                            select sheet.Cells[cell.Start.Row,cell.Start.Column,cell.Start.Row,2].Value)
                            .Cast<object[,]>()
                            .ToDictionary (k => k[0,0] as string, v => (double)(v[0,1]));

                //do what you need to do with the dictionary here....!
            }
        }
    }

}
```