# ClosedXML-generated xlsx file has formula errors when opened; using Azure Function App in C#

Tags: c#, azure-functions, xlsx, closedxml

I have been tasked with creating automation that generates an xlsx file once a day and then sends it via email to a designated recipient. The Excel file contains formulas. Using Azure Function App in C# for the automation, I've encountered a formula error involving the '@' symbol when I open the generated Excel file.

[image: [Screenshot of the resulting Excel file showing the '@' formula error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hjkij.png)]

To generate the Excel file, I'm using the ClosedXML library. During debugging, I've verified that the formula is entered correctly. Given this, I was expecting the Excel file to open without any formula errors.

[image: [Code snippet where I set the formula using ClosedXML in C#.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40pCX.png)]

1. Has anyone encountered this issue before?
2. Is this a bug with the Excel file that hasn't been resolved?
3. Is there a way to remove this '@' symbol without resorting to VB code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Lior please share your code in the from of text

Comment: @Lior hope this reference [helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828687/read-column-index-and-column-value-from-an-excel-in-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Used this [reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19828687/read-column-index-and-column-value-from-an-excel-in-c-sharp)  for index. I set the formula in ClosedXML to calculate the sum of cells A1 and A2.

**Code:**

```cs
 worksheet.Cell("A3").FormulaA1 = "SUM(A1:A2)";

 // Save the workbook to a MemoryStream
 using (var stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
 {
     workbook.SaveAs(stream);

     // Log the output to the console
      _logger.LogInformation("Excel file generated successfully.");

     // Log the output to Azure Functions logs
     _logger.LogInformation($"Saving the file to Azure Blob Storage or sending it via email: {Convert.ToBase64String(stream.ToArray())}");
     _logger.LogInformation($"Next timer schedule at: {myTimer.ScheduleStatus.Next}");
 }
```

[image]

[image]

- For more details refer this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54980972/how-to-iterate-on-excel-range-with-an-index-in-c-sharp) and  uploading excel to [storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61597897/how-to-upload-a-blob-excel-file-to-an-azure-storage-account).